# Why vscode complain type missing properties while the code is actually working

Tags: typescript, axios, vuejs3, volar

I am newbie in TypeScript.

I have defined such types:

```
enum FilterLogic {
  AND = 'and',
  OR = 'or'
}

enum FilterOperator {
  EQUAL = 'eq',
  NOT_EQUAL = 'neq',
  IS_NULL = 'isNull',
  IS_NOT_NULL = 'isNotNull',
  LT = 'lt',
  LTE = 'lte',
  GT = 'gt',
  GTE = 'gte',
  STARTS_WITH = 'startsWith',
  NOT_STARTS_WITH = 'notStartsWith',
  ENDS_WITH = 'endsWith',
  NOT_ENDS_WITH = 'notEndsWith',
  CONTAINS = 'contains',
  NOT_CONTAINS = 'notContains',
  BETWEEN = 'between',
  NOT_BETWEEN = 'notBetween',
  IN = 'in',
  NOT_IN = 'notIn'
}

enum SortDirection {
    ASC = "asc",
    DESC = "desc"
}

export type Filter = {
  field: string;
  logic: FilterLogic;
  operator: FilterOperator,
  filters: Filter[]
};

export type Sort = {
    field: string,
    dir: SortDirection
};

export type SEAReadRequest = {
  includes?: string[];
  skip?: number;
  take?: number;
  search?: string;
  filter?: Filter;
  view?: string;
  sort?: Sort[];
};

export type SEAResponse<T> = {
    success: boolean,
    ecode?: string,
    emsg?: string,
    data?: T[],
    total?: number
};
```

axios steup:

```
import axios, { InternalAxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { useUserStoreHook } from '@/store/modules/user';

// 创建 axios 实例
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_BASE_API,
  timeout: 50000,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' }
});

// 请求拦截器
service.interceptors.request.use(
  (config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
    const userStore = useUserStoreHook();
    if (userStore.token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = userStore.token;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error: any) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// 响应拦截器
service.interceptors.response.use(
  (response: AxiosResponse) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    const { success, msg } = response.data;
    if (success === true) {
      return response.data;
    }
    // 响应数据为二进制流处理(Excel导出)
    if (response.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
      return response;
    }

    ElMessage.error(msg || '系统出错');
    return Promise.reject(new Error(msg || 'Error'));
  },
  (error: any) => {
    if (error.response.data) {
      const { code, msg } = error.response.data;
      // token 过期,重新登录
      if (code === 'A0230') {
        ElMessageBox.confirm('当前页面已失效，请重新登录', '提示', {
          confirmButtonText: '确定',
          type: 'warning'
        }).then(() => {
          localStorage.clear();
          window.location.href = '/';
        });
      } else {
        ElMessage.error(msg || '系统出错');
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error.message);
  }
);

// 导出 axios 实例
export default service;
```

api method：

```
export function getPlans(req: SEAReadRequest): AxiosPromise<SEAResponse<Plan>> {
  return request({
    url: '/sea/pms/plan',
    method: 'put',
    data: req
  });
}
```

now using axios like this (in .vue file):

```
function loadData() {
  loading.value = true;
  getPlans(req)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data); // output shows data is a SEAResponse<Plan> actually.
      plans.value = data.data;
      total.value = data.total || 0;
    })
    .finally(() => {
      loading.value = false;
    });
}
```

but VSCode complains about problems:
[image]

my vscode version: 1.77.0

and I am using Vue3's vscode extension volar with [take over mode](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode), if that matters.

> To get Vue SFCs and TypeScript working together, Volar creates a separate TS language service instance patched with Vue-specific support, and uses it in Vue SFCs. At the same time, plain TS files are still handled by VSCode's built-in TS language service, which is why we need TypeScript Vue Plugin to support Vue SFC imports in TS files. This default setup works, but for each project we are running two TS language service instances: one from Volar, one from VSCode's built-in service. This is a bit inefficient and can lead to performance issues in large projects.

Comment: It looks like `data` is an object of type `AxiosResponse`, while your data of type `SEAResponse<Plan>` is inside `data.data`, basically in order to access the array you should do `data.data.data`, while in order to access the `total` property you have to access it via `data.data.total`

Comment: In order to delete the first `data` object you can destructure the parameter of your `.then()` function, like `.then(({ data }) => ...)`, and then you should be able to do just `data.data` and `data.total`

Comment: To address the question in the title: typescript does not run in the browser.  It transpiles to javascript.  TS being a strongly typed superset of JS means invalid TS programs can still be considered valid JS programs as long as the errors are TS specific.  The fact you have type errors but your code still runs fine is then not a surprise.

Comment: @Nullndr sorry, I missed API method definition, Can you  take a look again?

Comment: @WestFarmer sorry but I don't think you are right about `data` being a `SEAResponse<Plan>`. The function `getPlans` is typed to return an `AxiosResponse<SEAResponse<Plan>>`, check the docs [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema)

Comment: @Nullndr it's the axios interceptor changed data type .`if (success === true) {
      return response.data;
    }`

Comment: @WestFarmer please could you provide a typescript playground link?